# Change ImageView background when radioButton is clicked inside RadioGroup

Tags: android, android-imageview, android-radiogroup

In my application I have two radio buttons which is place inside a Radio Group and I have single Image View. The two radio buttons choices name as sun and moon and my Image View is set to sun image.

I want to change the set image to moon when I clicked the radio button name moon. How can I do that inside the radio Group?

Answer (score 0):

```
RadioGroup radioGroup = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.[add your id here <---WITHOUT [].]);


int checkedRadioButton = radioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId();



switch (checkedRadioButton) {
 case R.id.radiobutton1 : imageview.setBackgroundImage(R.drawable.sun);
                              break;
 case R.id.radiobutton2 : image view.setBackgroundImage(R.drawable.moon);
                          break;
}
```

Note - this is only the functionality, without the xml. I suppose you are smart enough to manage to hook up this to your xml.

Note2 - I might be mistaking with this: setBackgroundImage. It might be a bit different.